Convergence of an inner product on a non-separable Hilbert space
I was reading about an example of non-separable Hilbert spaces and I came across this space:
Let $C(\mathbb{R})$  be the set of complex valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$ and define $\lVert .\rVert:C(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ by
$$\lVert f \rVert=\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_{-n}^{n}|f(x)|^2dx\right)^{1/2}$$
Then, define $$H_{0}:=\{f\in C(\mathbb{R}):\lVert f \rVert<\infty\}$$
So $\lVert.\rVert$ is a seminorm on $H_0$ and also define
$$I:=\{f \in H_0:\lVert f \rVert=0\}$$
Notice that $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R})\subset H_0$. Finally set $H_{1}=H_{0}/I$, so $H_{1}$ is a normed vector space and define the inner product on $H_1$:
$$(f+I,g+I)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_{-n}^{n}f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx$$
I have tried to prove that this inner product converges by showing that it is Cauchy in $\mathbb{C}$ but I couldn't. Also, I  notice that it is sufficient to show that for any $f,g\in H_0$, then $f+g\in H_0$ but I still don't know how to prove it.
Could you help me with this proof?

I would recommend using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for the integral $\int_{-n}^n f\overline{g} \ dx$ and seeing where that leads you.

The limit in the definition of $|f|$ does not seem to always converge. I suppose we’re restricting to those functions for whom the limit actually converges?

@DavidGao yes, we are restricting to those functions.
